# get_dummies causing column mismatch between train and test sets?

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, kaggle

Working on the Titanic dataset from kaggle and having an issue trying to handle categorical variables and deal with NA values. The following code produces this error:

```
import pandas as pd
from sklearn.preprocessing import Imputer

nonpredictors = ["Ticket", "Cabin", "Survived"]
nonpredictors_test = ["Ticket", "Cabin"]

training_df = pd.read_csv("train.csv").set_index(["PassengerId"])
training_df_concat = training_df.drop(nonpredictors, axis = 1)
testing_df = pd.read_csv("test.csv").set_index(["PassengerId"])
testing_df_concat = testing_df.drop(nonpredictors_test, axis = 1)
chunks = [training_df_concat, testing_df_concat]
all_data = pd.concat(chunks, ignore_index = True)
catVar = ["cabin_level", "Embarked", "Sex"]
all_data = pd.get_dummies(all_data, columns = catVar)
imp = Imputer(strategy = 'median')
imp.fit(all_data)

training_df = pd.get_dummies(training_df, columns = catVar)
train_x = training_df.drop(nonpredictors, axis = 1)
train_x = imp.transform(train_x)
train_y = training_df["Survived"]

testing_df = pd.get_dummies(testing_df, columns = catVar)
test_x = testing_df.drop(nonpredictors_test, axis = 1)
test_x = imp.transform(test_x)

ValueError: X has 20 features per sample, expected 21
```

I concatenate the datasets and fit the imputer on the resulting combination set to avoid the scenario that I fit it on a training set which contains values not observed in the test set.

Seems I'm getting a column mismatch between the train and test sets, but I can't see where. Any ideas? Thanks in advance.

Comment: On which line are you getting this error? On the `imp.transform()`?

Comment: You have taken care of the Imputer fit on all available data but `pd.get_dummies()` is not. You are calling `pd.get_dummies` on train and test separately which may lead to difference of columns due to some values only present in one and not other (either in train or test).